# Share button changes color after exporting app

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard, android-theme, android-sharing

**I think this is related to proguard; please see edits at bottom of post.**

I'm using eclipse to build a little android app.

When I run my app (by clicking on the green run button in eclipse, with my phone connected to my computer by USB), my share button looks like this:

[image: white share button]

..which is what I want.

When I file -> export my app and install the APK using `adb install` (or if I upload the new APK to the play store and install the update), my share button looks like this:

[image: black share button]

...which is unfortunate.

How do I get the button to look white in the exported app?

Some snippets from my code:

The menu item:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    android:title="@string/action_share"
    mysapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    myapp:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
```

My res/values/styles.xml:

```
<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
       <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

<style name="vertical_space">
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
</style>
```

res/values-v14/styles.xml:

```
<!--
    Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
    res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
```

I also have a values-v11/styles.xml with `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"`. I do not have a values-v21 dir.

**Edit 1**:

I'm trying to think of what changes when exporting the app versus just running it from eclipse.

One possibility is that I have proguard enabled in `project.properties`:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

Proguard is only active when exporting, right?  Not sure whether that could be an explanation.

**Edit 2**:

I commented out the proguard.config line in `project.properties` and the problem goes away, i.e. the share button is white when exporting the app.  I'd like to have proguard enabled, however. How can I both enable proguard and keep the button white when exporting?

Comment: Could you provide apk with error, link to dropbox or something else?

Comment: @gio in my user page you'll see a play store link to a version of the app with the dark share button.  Does that help?

Comment: does it contain error?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by error here.  It does contain the dark share button (second screenshot in my post), which is what I want to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're seeing this behavior. But, you can try explicitly defining the tint color for the share drawable. Something like this:

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
   <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
   <!-- Defining actionModeShareDrawable is not really required 
   <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#b3ffffff</item>
</style>
```

From what I can tell, the color referenced by attribute `textColorSecondary` is used to tint the share drawable. So, being explicit about the color might solve your problem. If you want me to mention how I singled out this attribute (I haven't tested if it even works :) ), let me know.

**Edit**

Browse to folder (SDK-INSTALLATION) / extras / android / support / v7 / appcompat / res / drawable-xhdpi.

Copy `abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha.png` and paste it to *your* application's `res/drawable-xhdpi` folder. Change its name to say - `changed_menu_share.png`.

Your theme should now look like:

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
   <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
   <item name="actionModeShareDrawable">@drawable/changed_menu_share</item>
</style>
```

This should make the Tintmanager ignore this drawable i.e. it will always be the color you intended - and, in this case, #ffffff. Also notice that we are no longer overriding `textColorSecondary` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.  I does cause the share button to be white when exporting, but it introduces a new problem: my EditTexts, which used to have a nice green underline, now switch from white to green whenever I swipe to a new fragment.

Comment: @Adrian Yes of course. But, this little test indicates that the problem you're having is - at some point, the framework provides the value of `textColorSecondary` as `#8a000000`, and not `#b3ffffff`. Let me look into this and get back to you.

Comment: @Adrian After looking through the `TintManager` class, I'm convinced that it uses the resource id of the drawable obtained from attribute `actionModeShareDrawable`. If we don't override this attribute in our theme, it gets defaulted to `R.drawable.abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha`. So, to prevent this, we can specify another drawable - and TintManger will ignore it.

Comment: @Adrian You're welcome. One suggestion - TintManager also changes the alpha value of the drawable - when dark, it uses alpha=#8a - when light, alpha="#b3". So, for consistency, you should open the png in an image-editing software and apply transparency according to alpha="#b3". Currently, alpha is set to `#ff`. You will also need to copy the pngs from various `drawable-XXXX` folders (in support library) to respective folders in your project. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the look shouldn't it be

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<!--
    Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
    res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
    backward-compatibility can go here.
-->
</style>
```

Comment: Just tried that and I get the same behavior as before: button is white when I run the app from eclipse, but black when I export and install the apk manually.

Comment: What's on values-v21 styles.xml ?

Comment: I don't have a values-v21, but I do have values-v14 and -v11.  Will post their contents.

Comment: Can we try to add this under your all AppBaseTheme in your values folders and see what happens 
`<item name=”colorAccent”>@color/white</item>` and define the color in your colors.xml?

Comment: That does not change the color of the share button (same behavior as before), but it does cause the bottom line in my EditText to become white.